# The proper pronunciation for "Message"

Tags: pronunciation

I am confused about the pronunciation of "message", if we look it up in a dictionary, the written phonetic is "ˈmes.ɪdʒ" (Cambridge Dictionary), but it is pronounced as if it was like "a" in hat ("hæt"). But, in IPA for English "e" is not "æ", for example red has a phonetic like "red". I have listened to the pronunciation for that word in many different places like forvo, Longman Dictionary and so on. So where is the problem? Why is message pronounced like "ˈmæs.ɪdʒ" although it has to be "ˈmes.ɪdʒ"?
It was a little hard for me to clearly explain it, but I hope I could tell it.

Comment: At least in the following dictionaries, if you listen to it, it is pronounced as [ɛ] (the vowel in *pet*):  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/message), [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/message), [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=message), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/message), [Macmillian](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/message_1), and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/message?a=british).

Comment: Note that many of these dictionaries don't use IPA for pronunciation keys; for example, in [this guide](http://www.ahdictionary.com/application/resources/misc/pronkey.pdf) to pronunciation in American Heritage dictionary, they say that for the IPA [ɛ], they use the symbol [ĕ].

Comment: The first syllable in "message" is pronounced like "mess-", not "mass-" or "miss-".

Comment: cf. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/language ; https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/language ; https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/language

Comment: It's not pronounced like *mæs.ɪdʒ*. I suspect your ears need practice distinguishing English vowels. Vowels in different languages (and in different dialects of English) don't correspond perfectly to each other.

Comment: @PeterShor It's a long time I've been learning English and I am not a newbie, but unfortunately, even in the links provided above, the pronunciation of "e" in message is not the same as "e" where I hear in a word like "red" on Cambridge or Longman or Oxford. Anyway thanks a lot to all of you dears

Comment: @A F: they may not be exactly the same vowel (and in fact, they probably aren't, because the exact vowel is influenced by the consonants surrounding it), but all your examples are heard as /ɛ/ and not as /æ/ by native English speakers. Try listening to the difference between *message* and *passage*.

Comment: Of course, some clown (like me) is apt to pronounce it  \mə-ˈsäzh\.

Comment: I assume this is because the preceding sound is /m/, a nasal, so the velum doesn't close until some point during the vowel, with the effect that it becomes hard to distinguish from /æ/. Compare the *pin-pen* merger and the lowering of French /ɛ̃/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be confused by the fact that the vowel sound in *red* is substantially longer than the vowel sound in *message,* primarily because the /s/ in message causes the preceding /ɛ/ to become shorter due to prefortis clipping.